# Software for translation memory

Tags: translation

"Translation memory" is software that maintains a database of past translations from a huge repository (typically created by accumulating `.po`-files from publicly available free software translation projects). When you type in a new phrase you want translated, it pull out the "best" matches from this repository and presents them for you.

This is, for instance, available as SAAS from [Transifex](http://support.transifex.com/customer/portal/articles/1156770-translation-memory), but I am looking for software that allows me to populate the translation memory repository.

This is for a free service I want to set up, so I would prefer free software, but I am willing to consider commercial solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) for two of my Open Source projects, and I am very happy with it.

By checking the option below, you get translation memory (it is off by default):

> Use Global TM
>
> By checking this option you will be able to leverage Crowdin Global Translation Memory,
>   it's a big vault of translations contributed by previous projects.
>
> Note! When checking this option any translations made in your project will be commited to Crowdin Global TM automatically!

Of course you need to understand the language and context, but it is very convenient, a lot of strings have already been translated by other projects so the propositions are often accurate.

Comment: I've checked that option, but how do I get access to TM results?  There is a tab "Concordance" that looks promising, but I always get "No results" unless I type in something *I* have already translated (then my translations, and only my translations, are found).